# Magento 2 - Multiple prices on one product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, price, product-prices

I am wondering if there is any basic idea on how to achieve multiple prices on one product (configurable product with multiple downloadable products) as you know it from a typical ticket sale.

**Example, Ticket for event 1:**
A ticket for a specific event can be configured and has multiple prices for:

- Adults, 100€
- Children, 80€
- Children (younger than 6), 0,00€
- ...

**Example, Ticket for event 2:**
A ticket for a specific event can be configured and has multiple prices for:

- Adults, 150€
- Children, 75€
- Children (younger than 6), 0,00€
- ...

As you can see the difference between the prices is not always the same. On the product detail page, you should be able to see the different groups and to increase/decrease the number of people, each increase/decrease would update the price.

I couldn't find any plugin or general approach how to achieve that and would probably go for setting up different prices fields for each "buyer group" (adults, children,...).

Comment: Maybe you can achieve your preffered result with Customizable options instead of a Configurable product?

Comment: No, as I need configurable products for "configuring" the product with other details, i. e. the date of the event, and filtering.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a configurable product.

Event 1 is a configurable product with 3 configurations:

- Adults, 100€
- Children, 80€
- Children (younger than 6), 0,00€ etc...

Same for event 2.

More info can be seen in here:

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for price based on **customer group** you can use **Tier Price**.

Tier Price is generally defined to give discount based on qty purchased. But you can use it for single quantity also by setting qty 1 and price based on customer group.

You can refer to magento documentation for setting [Product Tier Price](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html)

Comment: No, I am not looking for customer group pricing. That does not fulfill the needs.